# Get user input x times and output all dog data sets

Tags: ruby, loops

I am creating a program which creates a record for a Dog, that has the attributes (id, breed year born, and name). I have to use arrays to store the attributes of 3 dogs and then print them to the terminal.

```
require './input_functions'

class Dog
  attr_accessor :id, :breed, :year_born, :name

  def initialise (id, breed, year_born, name)
    @id = id
    @breed = breed
    @year_born = year_born
    @name = name
  end
end

# Complete the missing code below

# Note: If your tasks requires outputting a floating point number you may wish to use the following:
# print out my_variable with 2 decimal places:
# printf("$%.2f\n", my_variable)
def read_dog()
  puts "Enter the ID of your dog"
  $dog_id = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the Breed of your dog"
  $dog_breed = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the birth year of your dog"
  $dog_year_born = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the name of your dog"
  $dog_name = gets.to_s

end

def display_dog
  puts $dog_id + "The dog ID is an Integer which is unique to your dog"
  puts $dog_breed + "The dog breed is a String which defines the ancestors of your dog"
  puts $dog_year_born + "The year born is an Integer which contains what year your dog was born"
  puts $dog_name + "The dog name is a String which contains what your dog's name is"
end

def read_dogs
  dogs = Array.new
  index = 0
  while (index < 3)
    dogs << read_dog[index]
    index = index + 1
  end
  return dogs
end

def display_dogs(dogs)
  index = 0
  while (index < 3)
    dogs[display_dog.to_i]
  index = index + 1
  end
end

def main
    dogs = read_dogs
  display_dogs(dogs)
end

main
```

The expected result is that the program displays all entered information back to the user. What happens instead is that only the last set of data that is entered is shown three times. It obviously has something to do with how I am storing or extracting the data from the array but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Not sure if this fixes your issue, but you misspelt `initialize`.

Comment: @SagarPandya: The `Dog` class is never used anywhere in the code, so it cannot possibly have to do anything with the problem. In fact, I am not sure why the OP even included it in the question, since it is never used.

Comment: I don't get this display_dog.to_i thing and I don't get why you don't use Dog.new and global ($) variables instead, see my answer below with a working example.

Comment: Might be coming from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must return some value from read_dog method

```
def read_dog()
  puts "Enter the ID of your dog"
  $dog_id = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the Breed of your dog"
  $dog_breed = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the birth year of your dog"
  $dog_year_born = gets.to_s
  puts "Enter the name of your dog"
  $dog_name = gets.to_s

  return [$dog_id, $dog_breed, $dog_year_born, $dog_name]
end
```

Let me update you on other things as it only printing last information
Btw I am not seeing any use of Dog class code in your snippet at the moment

Comment: Why are you using global variables ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :id, :breed, :year_born, :name

  def self.ask_for_dogs(n_times)
    all_dogs = []
    n_times.times do
      all_dogs << new
    end
    all_dogs
  end

  def self.display(dogs)
    dogs.each do |dog|
      puts "Id: #{dog.id}"
      puts "Name: #{dog.name}"
      puts "Breed: #{dog.breed}"
      puts "Year born: #{dog.year_born}\n"
    end
  end

  private 

  def initialize
    puts "Enter the dog's ID:"
    @id = gets.to_s
    puts "Enter the dog's breed:"
    @breed = gets.to_s
    puts "Enter the dog's birth year:"
    @year_born = gets.to_s
    puts "Enter the dog's name:"
    @name = gets.to_s
  end
end
```

Run it, by defining the number of dogs you want to create. 
In the loop dog objects are created, which are then printed out by the diplay method all at once, by accessing the attributes of the dog object.

```
dogs = Dog.ask_for_dogs(3)
Dog.display(dogs)
```